# When given Json file names as input "org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]"

Tags: java, json, jsonexception, object-relationships

When given Json file names as input "org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]"

[image][image]`[image: enter code here]

The following files are used in the below code.

```
JSONObject output1 = new JSONObject("E:\\Bharathi\\json sample files\\example_1.json")
JSONObject output2 = new JSONObject("E:\\Bharathi\\json sample files\\example_2.json")

//JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) readJsonSimpleDemo("example.json");

jsonsEqual(output1, output2)

def jsonsEqual(Object obj1, Object obj2) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject diff = new JSONObject();

    println("Object1 get class: "+obj1.getClass())
    println("Object2 get class: "+obj2.getClass())

    if (!obj1.getClass().equals(obj2.getClass())) {
      return diff;
    }

    if (obj1 instanceof JSONObject && obj2 instanceof JSONObject) {
      JSONObject jsonObj1 = (JSONObject) obj1;

      JSONObject jsonObj2 = (JSONObject) obj2;

      List<String> names = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(JSONObject.getNames(jsonObj1)));
      List<String> names2 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(JSONObject.getNames(jsonObj2)));
      if (!names.containsAll(names2) && names2.removeAll(names)) {
        for (String fieldName : names2) {
          if(jsonObj1.has(fieldName))
            diff.put(fieldName, jsonObj1.get(fieldName));
          else if(jsonObj2.has(fieldName))
            diff.put(fieldName, jsonObj2.get(fieldName));
        }
        names2 = Arrays.asList(JSONObject.getNames(jsonObj2));
      }

      if (names.containsAll(names2)) {
        for (String fieldName : names) {
          Object obj1FieldValue = jsonObj1.get(fieldName);
          Object obj2FieldValue = jsonObj2.get(fieldName);
          Object obj = jsonsEqual(obj1FieldValue, obj2FieldValue);
          if (obj != null && !checkObjectIsEmpty(obj))
            diff.put(fieldName, obj);
        }
      }
      return diff;
    } else if (obj1 instanceof JSONArray && obj2 instanceof JSONArray) {

      JSONArray obj1Array = (JSONArray) obj1;
      JSONArray obj2Array = (JSONArray) obj2;
      if (!obj1Array.toString().equals(obj2Array.toString())) {
        JSONArray diffArray = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < obj1Array.length(); i++) {
          Object obj = null;
          matchFound: for (int j = 0; j < obj2Array.length(); j++) {
            obj = jsonsEqual(obj1Array.get(i), obj2Array.get(j));
            if (obj == null) {
              break matchFound;
            }
          }
          if (obj != null)
            diffArray.put(obj);
        }
        if (diffArray.length() > 0)
          return diffArray;
      }
    } else {
      if (!obj1.equals(obj2)) {
        return obj2;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  def checkObjectIsEmpty(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null)
      return true;
    String objData = obj.toString();
    if (objData.length() == 0)
      return true;
    if (objData.equalsIgnoreCase("{}"))
      return true;
    return false;
  }
```

Running this code I received the following Error :

> When given Json file names as input "org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]"

Comment: And what exactly is the question?

Comment: Could you please share[code] the way you are loading Json ? I feel there is some issue with that.

Comment: Most probably because the JSONObject constructor expects a JSON string as argument, not the path of a file containing JSON. Read the javadoc.